# Why can't I run a query against my has many relationship in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table called `Group` which has many `Person` through `groups_people`. This is that part of the `Group` table:

```
class Group:
...
...
  people = db.relationship('Person', secondary=groups_people,
    backref=db.backref('groups', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Here is my `groups_people` table:

```
groups_people = db.Table('groups_people',
db.Column('group_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('group.id')),
db.Column('person_id',db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('person.id')))
```

My `class Person` table does not have any group relationships listed in it.

This all works except that when I call `group.people` it returns an `InstrumentedList`.  I want to run a query on all the `people` of that `group`. I cannot.

**How do I run a filter query against the `people` of that `group`? Or: how do I get it to return an object I can query?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the backref marked `lazy='dynamic'`, you need to mark the relationship itself that way.

```
class Group(db.Model):
    ...
    people = db.relationship(Person, lambda: groups_people, lazy='dynamic',
        backref=db.backref('groups', lazy='dynamic'))
    ...
```